# How to install Android Studio with Flutter on Ubuntu 20.04

Tags: software-installation, android

Sorry if this was asked before.

What is the *current* proper way of installing Android Studio to be able to develop applications using Flutter on Ubuntu 20.04 ?

On the Android Studio install page (https://developer.android.com/studio/install) it is recommended to use the /opt directory:

> Unpack the .zip file you downloaded to an appropriate location for your applications, such as within /usr/local/ for your user profile, or /opt/ for shared users.

I extracted the archive into /opt using *sudo* and then I also had to use sudo to run the start script.

But I would like to start the Android Studio without using *sudo*.

Thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would recommend to add ([Ubuntu Make PPA](https://wiki.ubuntu.com/ubuntu-make)) and install Android Studio using it

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:lyzardking/ubuntu-make
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install ubuntu-make
umake android
```

the last command will install Android Studio to your home folder with corresponding shortcuts.

Comment: Thanks it worked! 
umake installed the required dependencies and android studio in 
`$HOME/.local/share/umake/android/android-studio`.
Logged in as a normal user without _sudo_ I could start the script 
`$HOME/.local/share/umake/android/android-studio/bin/studio.sh`
Then I added a desktop shortcut from "Android Studio > Tools > Create desktop entry" and the shortcut was available in the Applications menu.
For Flutter I installed the _Flutter_ plugin in Android Studio.