# How to install Android Virtual Emulator on Ubuntu 20.04.3. Not Genymotion or virtualbox

Tags: android, android-emulator

I just wanted to download an Android Emulator that isn't Genymotion or related with virtualbox. With EMULATOR being the keyword here, I don't want to download it as an OS.
I just want like an app. For example: LDplayer. LDplayer is used to play android games on PC (Windows) But I want an alternate to this software so I can play android games on Linux.
Thanks in advance.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to install Android Studio with Flutter on Ubuntu 20.04](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1372680/how-to-install-android-studio-with-flutter-on-ubuntu-20-04) . Then launch AVD from Configure → AVD Manager.

Comment: Can I play android games?

Comment: I'm not sure about graphics acceleration.

Comment: I want to install an Android emulator on my laptop because I want to play android games and use android software.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use [Anbox](https://anbox.io/).

Here is the full description of the debian package

> [Android in a box](https://packages.debian.org/unstable/anbox)

> Anbox is a container-based approach to boot a full Android system on a regular GNU/Linux system.

> In other words: Anbox will let you run Android on your Linux system without the slowness of virtualization.

> Anbox uses Linux namespaces (user, pid, uts, net, mount, ipc) to run a full Android system in a container and provide Android applications on any GNU/Linux-based platform.

> The Android inside the container has no direct access to any hardware. All hardware access is going through the anbox daemon on the host. It reuses what Android implemented within the QEMU-based emulator for OpenGL ES accelerated rendering. The Android system inside the container uses different pipes to communicate with the host system and sends all hardware access commands through these.

Anbox can be installed through `snap` or `apt`.

Using `snap`: see [Install the Anbox snap](https://docs.anbox.io/userguide/install.html#install-the-anbox-snap).

On Ubuntu versions prior to Focal, you need to install and load the kernel module before executing the `snap` command:

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:morphis/anbox-support
sudo apt update
sudo apt install anbox-modules-dkms
sudo modprobe ashmem_linux
sudo modprobe binder_linux
```

On Ubuntu Focal, Hirsute, Impish and Jammy, Anbox can be installed through `apt`:

```
sudo add-apt-repository multiverse
sudo apt update
sudo apt install anbox
```

Comment: Do I have to boot from it in order to run it?

Comment: @MaheswarKARAKKATTUKISHORKUM No, you can run it like an installed app.

Comment: Excuse me, Anbox dosent open.

Comment: And also can you tell me how to remove everything.